# How to use router-outlet not to append content but to replace

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I've an angular site and I've used a html/css theme and apply that theme for app component.

my app component is like this below (I've nested components,I've many components but i've put only few here)

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-body-part></app-body-part>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now i need to add a member area.

I've configured routers as below

```
  {path: 'member-area',component:MemberAreaComponent}
```

But for that i do not want to have above html/css theme for that member-area
In above example it member-area component will be just below the 
 section.

i need to replace above 3 components , not appending

What would be the approach ? 
Do i need to delete app component content and use a separate component to include currently existing components?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You can apply styles in your component if u want to use specific styles. Regarding the issue of show 3 component and in some case replace all the three with 1 component, I would suggest u to have a look at Guard. If there is a conditional logic on that, u can activate a Guard and change the routing to the needed component

Comment: `<router-outlet>` is used to show a Component rather than another, according to client url. It's not clear what you are attempting to do. If you want to show or hide the above components according to url, then that's the wrong place to stay

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own.
I created a new component 'main' and copied whatever i had in app component.

Then i removed everything in app component and used only the

and created a new router path like below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'member-area',component:MemberAreaComponent},
  {path: '',component:MainComponent}
];
```